# Is there a way to reliably get the MAC address of an onboard network adapter in Windows 10 with C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm looking to reliably retrieve the MAC address of the onboard network adapter for any machine running Windows 10 using C++. However, when I plug in an external network adapter (in this case a USB to ethernet device) I've found that my code will sometimes read the MAC address for this device instead of the onboard one.

I've been using the [GetAdapterInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) function, iterating over the list of adapters and using the index from [the IP adapter info structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_info) to pick the earliest one as [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13421/Getting-the-Physical-MAC-address-of-a-Network-Inte) led me to believe that the adapter with the lowest index would be an onboard one (though the author does note that they can't find a reliable source for this).

I did notice this in the description for the index field in the IP_ADAPTER_INFO structure:

> The adapter index may change when an adapter is disabled and then enabled, or under other circumstances, and should not be considered persistent.

So maybe that indicates that I can't necessarily trust this index value.

I have also looked over the [GetAdapterAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) function, but it doesn't look like I'll get a better network adapter index from the list that this returns.

Any help/insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If this is for some type of licensing, someone could have multiple on board NICs and also could change / spoof the MAC address  reported by the hardware.

Comment: This is true, it's easy to spoof the MAC address and cause problems. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to change this in the software I'm working on

Comment: If you are counting on this for licensing, you are in for a world of disappointment and customer frustration.  Particularly if you get a customer with computers that are required to disable on-board NICs.    We often had customers plug in some network device which would suddenly change the reported NIC.  We finally had to ditch all use of NICs in device HOSTIDs for this reason.